# cannot find lcblas ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, compiling, install-from-source

I was trying to use the make file of a program and I hit the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
```

I tried the solution from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/atlas/+bug/769180 but it did not work. Can some one help me out with this?

Comment: Have you installed `libatlas-base-dev` package? Can you give more info on what have you tried to fix this (how have you created the symlinks)?

Comment: @Salem Thanks, installing libatlas-base-dev resolved this issue.

Comment: Please write an answer describing what have you done and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 13):

installing [libatlas-base-dev [image: Install libatlas-base-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libatlas-base-dev) solved the problem.